# woocommerce displaying instructions for downloadable products only on thank you page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to woocommerce and wordpress and what I am trying to achieve is display instructions on thank you page for download-able products only.

May be I am wrong but I have this file I am looking at `woocommerce->templates->order->order-details.php` and it has the following piece of code that outputs the download links on thankyou page (i assume as i am not able to find another file that does this job).

```
    if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $_product->is_downloadable() && $order->is_download_permitted() ) {
echo 'Click the links below to access your courses. You will also receive an email shortly with the links to download your products.';
        $download_files = $order->get_item_downloads( $item );
        $i              = 0;
        $links          = array();

        foreach ( $download_files as $download_id => $file ) {

            $i++;

            $links[] = '<small style="font-size: 15pt !important;"><a href="' . esc_url( $file['download_url'] ) . '">' . sprintf( __( 'Download file%s', 'woocommerce' ), ( count( $download_files ) > 1 ? ' ' . $i . ': ' : ': ' ) ) . esc_html( $file['name'] ) . '</a></small>';
        }

        echo '<br/>' . implode( '<br/>', $links );
    }
```

Now all I want is to echo a text here for downloadable products only. But it does not display the text.

The text I want to echo is as following where the red arrow is pointing

**Click the links below to access your courses. You will also receive an email shortly with the links to download your products.;**

[image]

I will really appreciate if anyone can help me in this.

Comment: Do the links to the products appear on that page?

Comment: @mevius I have updated my question with a screenshot if that helps

Comment: Where do you want to print that message ? Into that table ?

Comment: Looks like you may be editing the wrong template...

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner right under where it says "Products" inside the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all **make sure** you have added **downloadable file(s)** from the **back end**. `My guess is, you have not added file`. So **add any file** from the `back end` in order to see the **message** that you have **inserted**.

See below pic and **make sure** you have both the things that is shown in below pic with **square box** :

[image]

After doing that, you will be able to see that **message**.

[image]

My **code** is in **same file** :

```
<td class="product-name">
<?php

    if ( $_product && ! $_product->is_visible() )
    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $item['name'], $item );
    else
    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', get_permalink( $item['product_id'] ), $item['name'] ), $item );

    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity_html', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times; %s', $item['qty'] ) . '</strong><br>', $item );

    $item_meta->display();

    if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $_product->is_downloadable() && $order->is_download_permitted() ) {
    echo "Click below link to download the file<br>";
    $download_files = $order->get_item_downloads( $item );
    $i              = 0;
    $links          = array();
    foreach ( $download_files as $download_id => $file ) {
    $i++;

    $links[] = '<small><a href="' . esc_url( $file['download_url'] ) . '">' . sprintf( __( 'Download file%s', 'woocommerce' ), ( count( $download_files ) > 1 ? ' ' . $i . ': ' : ': ' ) ) . esc_html( $file['name'] ) . '</a></small>';
                            }

    echo '<br/>' . implode( '<br/>', $links );
    }
    ?>
    </td>
```

Let me know if you have **any doubt**.